# Problem with Arrays in MYSQL query - Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, laravel

Laravel problem with the mysql database query.
I want that user to be able to enter max 3 phrases in the search engine. After entering them, the script is to scan the database in fields of the type (first name, last name, job description etc.) and display all who match the query.
And here comes the problem.
Probably the problem is in the array in the variable $listAll. 
For example: the variable $listAll show such values for some search: 
Array ([0] => 0 [1] => Array ([0] => 3 [1] => 5 [2] => 8 [3] => 11 [ 4] => 32))

And the database query only shows me one user (that one with ID 3 - first on array list). As if this query wasn't looping or something.

The question is - how to generate / process the $listAll variable to display all users whose ID is in $listAll in the database query?

```
    $listAll[] = 0;
    $list[] = 0;
    $categ[] = 0;
    $categAll[] = 0;
    $categUsers[] = 0;

       foreach ($searchArray as $arr) {

        if(strlen($arr) > 20){
            return redirect('/baza');
        }

    $list[1] = Hashtags::Where('tag', $arr)->pluck('users_id')->all();

    $list[2] = User::Where('name', 'LIKE', '%'.$arr.'%')->pluck('id')->all();

    $list[3] = User::Where('surname', $arr)->pluck('id')->all();

    $list[4] = User::Where('title', $arr)->pluck('id')->all();

    $list[5] = User::Where('description', 'LIKE', '%'.$arr.'%')->pluck('id')->all();

    $list[6] = User::Where('my_experience', 'LIKE', '%'.$arr.'%')->pluck('id')->all();

    $list[7] = User::Where('education', 'LIKE', '%'.$arr.'%')->pluck('id')->all();

    $list[8] = User::Where('profits_from', 'LIKE', '%'.$arr.'%')->pluck('id')->all();

    $categ = Categories::where('name', 'LIKE', '%'.$arr.'%')->orWhere('subname', 'LIKE', '%'.$arr.'%')->pluck('id')->all();

    if($categ)
    array_push($categAll, $categ);

    for($i = 1; $i < 9 ; $i++){
        if($list[$i])
        array_push($listAll, $list[$i]);
    }
        }

    $categUsers = User::whereHas('categories', function($q) use ($categAll){$q->whereIn('categories_id', $categAll);})->pluck('id')->all();



    $bazaAll = User::whereIn('id', $listAll)
                                ->when(!empty($categUsers), function ($query) use ($categUsers){
                                    return $query->orWherein('id', $categUsers);})
                                ->whereHas('roles', function($q){$q->whereIn('roles_id', ['3']);})
    ->simplePaginate(10);
```

Comment: The question is not clear

Comment: For example:
the variable $listAll show such values for some search: 
Array ([0] => 0 [1] => Array ([0] => 3 [1] => 5 [2] => 8 [3] => 11 [ 4] => 32))

And the database query only shows me one user (that one with ID 3 - first on array list). As if this query wasn't looping or something.

The question is - how to generate / process the $listAll variable to display all users whose ID is in $ listAll in the database query?

Comment: How is categories related to users, because there is quite an easier way of doing it, but need to know the relations